# Especify BUILD Port for react JS

Tags: reactjs

When I run npm run build. And then run npm serve -s on the build folder. It outputs :
Local:            http://localhost:5000
However I would that the application to run at localhost:3000. How do I specify that.

Answer (score 0):

serve -s build -l *specific port*